# Exim configure Relay

Tags: centos, exim

I have a VPS with Directadmin which also has Exim installed.
Im trying to configure it so the websites hosted on the machine are allowed to relay through Exim. I have configured Exim with a smarthost.

However when i try to have a website send mail through localhost it will ask for Authentication.
I have the following added to hostlist

```
hostlist relay_from_hosts = ::1
```

And added the following to the ACL

```
accept  hosts = +relay_from_hosts
endpass
```

This is the complete ACL:

```
######################################################################
#                               ACLs                                 #
######################################################################

begin acl

# ACL that is used after the RCPT command
check_recipient:


## My own Edit.
accept  hosts = +relay_from_hosts
    endpass

# to block certain wellknown exploits, Deny for local domains if
# local parts begin with a dot or contain @ % ! / |
  deny  domains       = +local_domains
        local_parts   = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]

# to restrict port 587 to authenticated users only
# see also daemon_smtp_ports above
accept  hosts = +auth_relay_hosts
        condition = ${if eq {$interface_port}{587} {yes}{no}}
        endpass
        message = relay not permitted, authentication required
        authenticated = *

# allow local users to send outgoing messages using slashes
# and vertical bars in their local parts.
# Block outgoing local parts that begin with a dot, slash, or vertical
# bar but allows them within the local part.
# The sequence \..\ is barred. The usage of @ % and ! is barred as
# before. The motivation is to prevent your users (or their virii)
# from mounting certain kinds of attacks on remote sites.
  deny  domains       = !+local_domains
        local_parts   = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\\.\\./

# local source whitelist
# accept if the source is local SMTP (i.e. not over TCP/IP).
# Test for this by testing for an empty sending host field.
  accept  hosts = :

# sender domains whitelist
# accept if sender domain is in whitelist
  accept  sender_domains = +whitelist_domains

# sender hosts whitelist
# accept if sender host is in whitelist
  accept  hosts = +whitelist_hosts
  accept  hosts = +whitelist_hosts_ip

# envelope senders whitelist
# accept if envelope sender is in whitelist
  accept  senders = +whitelist_senders

# accept mail to postmaster in any local domain, regardless of source
  accept  local_parts = postmaster
          domains     = +local_domains

# accept mail to abuse in any local domain, regardless of source
  accept  local_parts = abuse
          domains     = +local_domains

# accept mail to hostmaster in any local domain, regardless of source
  accept  local_parts = hostmaster
          domains     =+local_domains

# OPTIONAL MODIFICATIONS:
# If the page you're using to notify senders of blocked email of how
# to get their address unblocked will use a web form to send you email so
# you'll know to unblock those senders, then you may leave these lines
# commented out.  However, if you'll be telling your senders of blocked
# email to send an email to errors@yourdomain.com, then you should
# replace "errors" with the left side of the email address you'll be
# using, and "example.com" with the right side of the email address and
# then uncomment the second two lines, leaving the first one commented.
# Doing this will mean anyone can send email to this specific address,
# even if they're at a blocked domain, and even if your domain is using
# blocklists.

# accept mail to errors@example.com, regardless of source
#   accept  local_parts = errors
#           domains     = example.com

# deny so-called "legal" spammers"
  deny message = Email blocked by LBL - to unblock see http://www.example.com/
       # only for domains that do want to be tested against RBLs
       domains = +use_rbl_domains
       sender_domains = +blacklist_domains

# deny using hostname in bad_sender_hosts blacklist
  deny message = Email blocked by BSHL - to unblock see http://www.example.com/
       # only for domains that do want to be tested against RBLs
       domains = +use_rbl_domains
       hosts = +bad_sender_hosts

# deny using IP in bad_sender_hosts blacklist
  deny message = Email blocked by BSHL - to unblock see http://www.example.com/
       # only for domains that do want to be tested against RBLs
       domains = +use_rbl_domains
       hosts = +bad_sender_hosts_ip

# deny using email address in blacklist_senders
  deny message = Email blocked by BSAL - to unblock see http://www.example.com/
  domains = use_rbl_domains
  deny senders = +blacklist_senders

# By default we do NOT require sender verification.
# Sender verification denies unless sender address can be verified:
# If you want to require sender verification, i.e., that the sending
# address is routable and mail can be delivered to it, then
# uncomment the next line. If you do not want to require sender
# verification, leave the line commented out

#require verify = sender

# deny using spamhaus
  deny message = Email blocked by SPAMHAUS - to unblock see http://www.example.com/
       # only for domains that do want to be tested against RBLs
        hosts = !+relay_hosts
       domains = +use_rbl_domains
       !authenticated = *
       dnslists = zen.spamhaus.org

# deny using njabl
#  deny message = Email blocked by NJABL - to unblock see http://www.example.com/
#       hosts = !+relay_hosts
#       domains = +use_rbl_domains
#       !authenticated = *
#       dnslists = dnsbl.njabl.org

# deny using cbl
#  deny message = Email blocked by CBL - to unblock see http://www.example.com/
#       hosts = !+relay_hosts
#       domains = +use_rbl_domains
#       !authenticated = *
#       dnslists = cbl.abuseat.org

## deny using sorbs name based list
#  deny message = Email blocked by SORBS - to unblock see http://www.example.com/
#       domains =+use_rbl_domains
#       # rhsbl list is name based
#       dnslists = rhsbl.sorbs.net/$sender_address_domain

# accept if address is in a local domain as long as recipient can be verified
  accept  domains = +local_domains
          endpass
      message = "Unknown User"
          verify = recipient

# accept if address is in a domain for which we relay as long as recipient
# can be verified
  accept  domains = +relay_domains
          endpass
          verify=recipient

# accept if message comes for a host for which we are an outgoing relay
# recipient verification is omitted because many MUA clients don't cope
# well with SMTP error responses. If you are actually relaying from MTAs
# then you should probably add recipient verify here

  accept  hosts = +relay_hosts
  accept  hosts = +auth_relay_hosts
          endpass
          message = authentication required
          authenticated = *
  deny    message = relay not permitted

# default at end of acl causes a "deny", but line below will give
# an explicit error message:
  deny    message = relay not permitted

# ACL that is used after the DATA command
check_message:
  #.include_if_exists /etc/exim.clamav.conf
  accept
```

When i look in the Exim logging i see the following:

```
2017-01-20 11:05:04 H=localhost (Websiteaddress) [::1] X=TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256 F=<emailaddress> rejected RCPT <emailaddress>: authentication required
2017-01-20 11:05:04 H=localhost (Websiteaddress) [::1] incomplete transaction (QUIT) from <emailaddress>
2017-01-20 11:05:04 H=localhost (Websiteaddress) [::1] F=<emailaddress> rejected RCPT <emailaddress>: authentication required
2017-01-20 11:05:04 H=localhost (Websiteaddress) [::1] incomplete transaction (QUIT) from <emailaddress>
2017-01-20 11:15:01 H=localhost (Websiteaddress) [::1] X=TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256 F=<emailaddress> rejected RCPT <emailaddress>: authentication required
2017-01-20 11:15:01 H=localhost (Websiteaddress) [::1] incomplete transaction (QUIT) from <emailaddress>
2017-01-20 11:15:01 H=localhost (Websiteaddress) [::1] F=<emailaddress> rejected RCPT <emailaddress>: authentication required
2017-01-20 11:15:01 H=localhost (Websiteaddress) [::1] incomplete transaction (QUIT) from <emailaddress>
```

Comment: Please provide in question all acl section from your exim config.

Comment: Editted the question with the entire ACL

Comment: in regards to your answer which you deleted. auth_relay_hosts = *  and relay_hosts points to an empty file.  im guessing this is what goes wrong. what would be the best way to change it?

Comment: Once i change auth_relay_hosts = *  to some random IP like 1.1.1.1  i'll get the error 'Relay not permitted' adding ::1 to relay_hosts has no effect